# nginx won't respond to monit

Tags: nginx, monit

Although EngineX is running, monit can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my monit log:

```
[PDT Apr 13 02:19:19] error    : HTTP error: Server returned status 400
[PDT Apr 13 02:19:19] error    : 'nginx' failed protocol test [HTTP] at INET[localhost:80] via TCP
[PDT Apr 13 02:19:19] info     : 'nginx' trying to restart
[PDT Apr 13 02:19:19] info     : 'nginx' stop: /etc/init.d/nginx
[PDT Apr 13 02:19:20] info     : 'nginx' start: /etc/init.d/nginx
```

The monitrc file contains the following configuration:

```
if failed port 80 protocol http and request '/ping.txt' # check for response
     with timeout 20 seconds
     then restart
```

I can access the file through **lynx http://localhost:80/ping.txt** without any problems.

Why would monit have trouble requesting the file when nginx is running just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out be the cause of version discrepancy.

My original monitrc file was intended for v5+, but the box it was running on used Monit 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Nginx older than 0.6.15 used to return 400 to requests like GET http://www.domain.com HTTP/1.0. I assume, you have updated Nginx in the last two years? If yes, please try to raise Nginx debugging level and post logs here.

Comment: Running nginx-0.8.35